# R base plot() function: Can I control the y-axis ranges and y-axis tick number orientation for each of these 3 plots in R base?

Tags: r, plot, time-series, timeserieschart

I can control the 3 y-axis labels, but I'd like to control each of the 3 y-axis ranges as well. Is this possible? I've tried 'ylim', but it only seems to accept a single range.

Also, I'd like to turn the y-axis tick numbers horizontal, if possible, so they don't overlap on each other.

Thanks for any input!

```
library(zoo)
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(date=seq.Date(as.Date("2020-12-01"), as.Date("2020-12-31"), "day"),
                  x=runif(31,0,5000),
                  y=runif(31,0,100),
                  z=runif(31,0,20))
rownames(dat) <- dat[,1]
dat <- dat[,-1]

plot(as.zoo(dat), ylab=c("label1","label2","label3"))
plot(as.zoo(dat), ylab=c("label1","label2","label3"), ylim=c(c(0,6000),c(0,150),c(0,50)))
```

[click here to see example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ew4L8.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems here:

- note that this is dispatching `plot.zoo` from the generic `plot`
- `as.zoo` should be `read.zoo` and the index in zoo objects are NOT row names.  See  `?zoo` and the vignettes that come with zoo `vignette(package = "zoo")` for more information about zoo objects or find them linked on the [zoo CRAN page](https://cran.r-project.org/package=zoo).   See `?read.zoo` and  `vignette("zoo-read", package = "zoo")` for more information on `read.zoo` in particular.
- in general it will be easier to deal with the code if you do NOT overwrite variables.  Below we have used `z` to represent the zoo object rather than destroying the original dat.
- to get multiple `ylim` sets they must be passed as a list of pairs.  The code in the question is passing a simple vector of 6 values.  See `?plot.zoo` for more information.
- add `las=1`.  See `?par` for more information.

Corrected, we have

```
library(zoo)

set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(date = seq.Date(as.Date("2020-12-01"), as.Date("2020-12-31"), "day"),
                  x = runif(31, 0, 5000),
                  y = runif(31, 0, 100),
                  z = runif(31, 0, 20))   
z <- read.zoo(dat)

ylab <- c("label1", "label2", "label3")
ylim <- list(c(0, 6000), c(0, 150), c(0, 50))
plot(z, ylab = ylab, ylim = ylim, las = 1)
```

giving:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna plot the three data individually, and then use the package **patchwork** to assemble them :

```
plot1 <- plot(...)
plot2 <- plot(...)
plot3 <- plot(...)
plot1 + plot2 + plot3 + patchwork::plot_layout(nrow = ..., ncol = ...)
```

And so, you can arrange the ylim for each of your plots :

```
plot1 <- plot(..., ylim = c(0,6000))
plot2 <- plot(..., ylim = c(0,150))
plot3 <- plot(..., ylim = c(0,50))
```

Comment: And using plot(..., las=1) as argument should do it for the y-axis ticks orientation.